# Rails: Getting a client side bit of data to server side model callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to start sending google analytics events from our backend, because new records can be created in a variety of different ways, different controllers, different templates and UIs. Tracking new items being created at the common point of code that they all have to go through just makes sense.

But to do that, I need a `clientId` for each user, which comes from the google analytics client side javascript.

```
class MyModel
  after_create :create_analytics_event
  def create_analytics_event
    GoogleAnalytics.event('foo', 'bar', client_id)
    #                                   ^ how do I get this in here
  end
end
```

The problem is that I don't want to explicitly pass this in from all controllers that would create these records.

In the past, I've stuck them on a global object somewhere like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_current_ga_client_id
  after_filter :clear_current_ga_client_id

  def set_current_ga_client_id
    User.current_ga_client_id = session[:ga_client_id]
  end

  def clear_current_ga_client_id
    User.current_ga_client_id = nil
  end
end
```

But this feels like an abuse of the assumption of single threading.

Is there a better way to do this implicitly? Or is doing this implicitly just a bad idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I settled on an around filter, which seems a bit cleaner.

```
# in ApplicationController
around_filter :set_backend_analytics_client_id
def set_backend_analytics_client_id
  GoogleAnalyticsApi.current_ga_client_id = session[:ga_client_id]
  yield
  GoogleAnalyticsApi.current_ga_client_id = nil
end
```

Which seems to be at least much clearer about what's going on.